# get counts of null and not null dates in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql named cfixed table like as shown below

[image]

I need to get the counts of Null and Not Null dates like as shown below

[image]

I have wrote a mysql query for getting the count of not null and null dates like a shown below

**For getting Not null dates counts for the date but not showing 0 count**

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) counts FROM cfixed WHERE fixed IS NOT NULL GROUP BY date
```

**For getting null dates counts for the date but not showing 0 count**

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) counts FROM cfixed WHERE fixed IS NULL GROUP BY date
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get the counts of null and not null within a single query

Comment: but you have 2 fixed date for 01-03-2016 and you mean to have count 1?

Comment: also for  01-05-2016 you have 1 null and 1 fixed value, but in the expected result for  01-05-2016 only closed = 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count()` automatically counts only non-NULL values (if you provide a specific column).
For the NULL values you can use a conditional `sum()`

```
SELECT date, 
       COUNT(fixed) non_null_counts,
       SUM(fixed IS NULL) as null_counts
FROM cfixed 
GROUP BY date
```